# findOneAndUpdate is not working in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

Here is code to update db.

```
let profileUrl = 'example'
UserSchemaModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id:userId}, {$set: {profileUrl:profileUrl} }, {new:true})
.then((updatedUser:UserModel) => {
     console.log(updatedUser.profileUrl)
})
```

result:`undefined`

As you can see in the result, `profileUrl` field is not updated. so I have inserted `overwrite` option.
But it didn't work. Following error is appeared.

```
src/controllers/user.ts(267,106): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ new: true; overwrite: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ModelFindOneAndUpdateOptions'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'overwrite' does not exist in type 'ModelFindOneAndUpdateOptions'.
```

UserSchema is same to following.

```
{
    name:String,
    thumbnailImg:String,
    email:String,
    phone:Number,
    profileUrl:String
}
```

now saved data is same following.

```
[{
    _id:ObjectId("5ffe07805cbab00019cdbbcd"),
    name:"Jhon",
    thumbnailImg:"thumbnail_image_url",
    email:"jhon@gmail.com",
    phone:"1212121212",
}]
```

I have tried several times, but the result is same.
How can I fix this issue?
I think there are methods to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to match using the `_id` field which is defined as ObjectId type in your schema.
So in your query, try searching using the ObjectId type.

```js
let ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; 
let profileUrl = 'example'
UserSchemaModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: new ObjectId(userId)}, {
     $set: {
          profileUrl: profileUrl
     } 
}, {new:true}).then((updatedUser:UserModel) => {
     console.log(updatedUser.profileUrl)
})
```